# Changing vmFolder of existing VM

Tags: python, vmware, pyvmomi

Currently I've got a pice of code that lists all the `vmFolder.Childentities` through pyVmomi, these are used to structurize the VM's in vCenter.

But now I want to change the vmFolder of an existing virtual machine.

PS: I can't show any code because I'm currently at work

Answer (score 1):

You will want to use the [`MoveIntoFolder_Task`](https://pubs.vmware.com/vsphere-55/index.jsp#com.vmware.wssdk.apiref.doc/vim.Folder.html?path=7_0_0_2_6_12_19#moveInto) method on the vmFolder. Where "Folder" is the folder to move the VM to and "VMs" is your list of VMs to move, your code would be:

```
Folder.MoveIntoFolder_Task(VMs)
```